# Ist es in irgendeinem Kontext legitim, »Tau« über die Stufe der Verdrillung zu definieren?

Tags: meaning-in-context, technical-terminology

#### Hintergrund

Ein Kandidat für ein Minimalpaar für [ç] und [χ] im Deutschen sind *[tauchen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tauchen)* und *Tauchen* (kleines [Tau](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tau_Seil)). Nun ist aber im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch ein Tau über seine Größe charakterisiert und auch der Duden [definiert ein Tau als »starkes Seil«](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tau_Seil). Demnach wäre eine Verniedlichung widersinnig – ein Tauchen ist einfach ein Seil. Dieses Problem tritt jedoch nicht auf, wenn man ein *Tau* über andere Eigenschaften charakterisiert.

#### Eigentliche Frage

Eine mögliche solche Charakterisierung ist über den Grad der Verdrillung:

- Grad 4: *Tau,* bestehend aus verdrillten Seilen.
- Grad 3: *Seil,* bestehend aus verdrillten Schnüren.
- Grad 2: *Schnur* (auch: *Kordel, Zwirn),* bestehend aus verdrillten Fäden.
- Grad 1: *Faden* (auch: *Garn),* bestehend aus verdrillten Fasern.
- Grad 0: *Faser,* nicht verdrillt.

Eine derartige Hierarchie wird [im Wikipedia-Artikel zu Tauwerk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauwerk) beschrieben: *Faser → Faden → Garn → Kardeel → Seil → Tross.* Allerdings wird dies ohne Referenz behauptet und die Kette endet auch nicht mit *Tau.*

Meine Frage ist daher: Gibt es irgendeine Fachsprache, in der ein *Tau* nicht durch seine Dicke, sondern über den Grad der Verdrillung definiert ist? (Und damit *Tauchen* Sinn ergibt.)

Comment: Nur mal so als Idee: Es kann doch auch **dünne**, aber dennoch **starke** Seile geben. So etwas wäre dann per Definition immer noch ein Tau, eben nur dünn, also ein Täuchen. Stärke ist nicht dasselbe wie Dicke, auch wenn beide Eigenschaften oft korrelieren.

Comment: Ist das hier wirklich eine Frage, die sich noch mit der deutschen Sprache beschäftigt? Ein Tau-chen mag immernoch ein Tau sein, aber eben ein dünneres - und wenn ich unzufrieden damit bin kann ich das auf das allzu dünne Tau - eben das Tau-chen schieben. Ein Tau fürs Tauziehen ist ein Tau-chen verglichen mit einem Ankertau für größere Schiffe.. Tau-chen muss nur im Kontext Sinn ergeben, nicht im allgemeinen Fall.

Comment: Ein *kleines Schiff* ist ein *Boot* - trotzdem gibt es das Wort *Schiffchen*.

Comment: Als Beispielwort für das Minimalpaar cha/chi [sorry für die Ersatzschreibung hier] kann man Tauchen (kleines Tau) doch verwenden ganz egal, ob in irgend einer realen (fachsprachlichen?) Verwendung Tauchen (kleine Taue) vorkommen.

Comment: Warum hieße es nich "Täuchen" ?

Comment: @Beta   Es könnte wohl auch Täuchen heißen. Man findet Beispiele für beides: Maus - Mäuschen, Haus - Häuschen, Frau - Frauchen. Orientiert man sich an der Frau, wird aus Tau ein Tauchen. - Übrigens: Fauchen (was eine Katze macht) und Vauchen (ein kleiner Buchstabe "v") wären phonologisch auch Minimalpaare. Ein "Väuchen" halte ich aber für unwahrscheinlich. Höchstens als Witz vielleicht.

Comment: Ich war durch die Überschrift auf Tau als dickes Seil vorbereitet und habe erst den Bezug auf den Buchstaben gar nicht verstanden. Darum geht es in der Frage doch gar nicht - wieso wird die Frage mit diesem Exkurs eingeleitet? Auch der Link zum (ab)tauchen verwirrt nur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ethymologisch hat ein "Tau" zu einem "Seil" oder einer "Leine" keinen Unterschied in der "Dicke" oder "Verdrilltheit"- Das *Tau* stammt von *tow*, also "ziehen" ab, während das *Seil* denselben Ursprung wie *sail*, also "Segel" hat.

Für einen Seemann ist "Tau[werk]" ein Oberbegriff für alles, was seilähnlich ist - die Dicke ist dafür erstmal zweitrangig. Ein "dickes Tau" ist für ihn eine *Trosse*, ein dünneres eine *Leine*, ein noch dünneres *Garn*.

Zumindest in der Seemannssprache, also dort, wo die Begriffe herkommen, existiert deine angenommene "Hierarchie" also überhaupt nicht (Deswegen kommt das "Tau" in der verlinkten Wikipedia-Liste auch gar nicht vor).

Dass wir heute ausserhalb der seemännischen Fachsprache unter "Tau" ein dickes, in der Seefahrt verwendetes Seil verstehen, hat wohl eher damit zu tun, dass das Tauwerk, mit dem der Seemann sein Schiff vertäut, eben schon immer dicker war als der Strick, mit dem der Bauer im Binnenland sein Kalb anbindet.

Zum Diminuitiv: Die Existenz eines Wortes für ein kleineres Ding als das Große bedingt nicht, dass es den Diminuitiv nicht gäbe oder er nicht sinnvoll wäre:

- Schiff-Boot-Kahn
- Mann-Junge
- Riese-Zwerg

Obwohl alle diese Begriffe einen jeweils passenden "kleineren" Begriff besitzen, gibt es doch jeweils auch eine Verkleinerungsform. Der Diminuitiv wird nicht nur verwendet, um "absolute Größe" auszudrücken, sondern auch für andere Zwecke - um z.B etwas ins Lächerliche zu ziehen, wie z.B. ein "Rieschen".